# uninitialized constant error in a Rails 3.2.11 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

This was working in Rails 2.3.11. I upgraded the app to Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 3.2.11. Everything works except for my check mailings.

In check_mailings_controller.rb:

```
class CheckMailingsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def send_mail
    CheckEmail.send_check_mail
    ...
  end
end
```

In /lib/check_email.rb:

```
class CheckEmail
  def self.send_check_mail
    ...
  end
end
```

The error message I am getting:

```
uninitialized constant CheckMailingsController::CheckEmail
```

Shouldn't the class be initialized when the app boots?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
require "check_email"
```

to the top of your `CheckMailingsController.rb` file.